# How to project a FET transistor as an amplifier?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier

I am trying to solve a problem on using an FET transistor as an amplifier with the common source configuration. The model should be appropriate for high frequencies.

The problem gives the equivalent circuit for the AC analysis like below where gm is 4 mA/V:

[image: Equivalent circuit]

To model the circuit I used the DC circuit of the amplifier with common source and ended up with this:

[image: Equivalent DC circuit]

I found that Rg = Ri and Rs is given. But I am having difficulty in finding Rd and proper Vcc and Vss sources to make it work. Any advice on how to approach this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to bias the gate

Comment: Clarification: are you supposed to be using a MOSFET ot a JFET?

Comment: @DKNguyen Isn't the scheme of polarizing the transistor with Vcc and Vss correct?

Comment: @brhans any FET transistor is correct. I just happened to choose a MOSFET.

Comment: Your reply leads me to believe that you don't know the difference between them... MOSFETs and JFETs are generally not interchangeable.

Comment: Yes I know they are not interchangeable. I chose to use a MOSFET

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask. Are you just asking if you have Vcc and Vss are on the right end?

Comment: You're using the MOSFET as NMOS, but the symbol indicates a PMOS transistor.  The PMOS will be off as long as your gate voltage is above VSS.